# can't install gensim with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, gensim

I am trying to install gensim with the command :

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim
```

but I am gating the following:
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- gensim -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
my environment is shown in the pic :
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? The error message states that your python version is not compatible with gensim. Have you tried creating a virtual conda environment?

Comment: my problem is theat i am trying to download gensim but my python v did not accept  that how can i fix it ? no i did not tried to create  virtual conda environment...